# How to find the largest number in a list that is not X number?

Tags: python

Let's say I have two lists:

```py
x = [6,5,5,4]  
z = [5,5,4,3]
```

I want to find the largest number in each list that is not `5`.
So the max of `x` is `6` and the max of `z` is `4`.

My ideas:

1. Remove all `5` from both lists then find the max.
   OR
2. If `5` is the max, then return the second-highest number. If `5` is not the max, return the max.

Would you solve this another way?

Comment: so what's wrong with `max(e for e in x if e != 5)`?

Comment: `max(x, key=lambda k: float('-inf') if k == 5 else k)`

Comment: `max(filter(lambda e: e != 5, z))`

Comment: Would one of these methods be faster or more efficient than another?

Comment: @ChrisE, the fastest will be `max([e for e in z if e != 5])`

Comment: @ChrisE, [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knquz.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Check this.

```
x = [6,5,5,4]
z = [5,5,4,3]
print(max(e for e in x if e!=5))
print(max(f for f in z if f!=5))
```

Comment: This was my solution but I thought there might be a better way. I suppose I should trust my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

def max_excluding(it, num):
    try:
        return max(filter(lambda x: x != num, it))
    except ValueError:
        return

for x in [[6,5,5,4], [5,5,4,3], [5], [1]]:
    print(max_excluding(x, 5))
```

Output:

```
6
4
None
1
```

I find [filters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) over [iterators](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) easier to reason about than list comprehensions where the key part of the code is tucked away near the end of the line.

I am, however, surprised to find that it results in code that takes almost 25%-30% longer:

```
import timeit

cases = {
    'comprehension': {
        'setup': "\n".join([
            'import random',
            'X = [int(random.randint(0, 10)) for _ in range(1000000)]',
        ]),
        'stmt': 'max([x for x in X if x != 5])',
    },
    'filter': {
        'setup': "\n".join([
            'import random',
            'X = [int(random.randint(0, 10)) for _ in range(1000000)]',
        ]),
        'stmt': 'max(filter(lambda x: x != 5, X))',
    },
}

for case, code in cases.items():
    print(case)
    print(timeit.timeit(**code, number=100))
```

Sample timing output:

```
comprehension
11.6845581
filter
14.393007899999999
```

Comment: Using list comprehension (not generator **!!**) is faster because data is already formed and there's no additional layers, while `filter()` returns an iterator and it takes additional resources to build data before sorting.